Normalized basic sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ with positive distance to a hyperplane.
This is an exercise from Diestel's "Sequences and Series in Banach spaces":
Suppose $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a normalized basic sequence in a Banach space $X$. If there is $f \in E^*$ so that
$f(x_n) \geq c > 0$ for all $n \geq 0$
show that $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is equivalent to the unit vector basis in $l^1$.
Note if $\sum_{n \geq 0}a_nx_n$ converges, then it must converge conditionally and if all the coefficients have the same sign, then $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx_n$ converges if and only if $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is in $l^1$.
